# Is there any difference between using SYS_syscallname __NR_syscallname in seccomp?

Tags: bpf, seccomp

Which is the difference between using SYS_syscallname and __NR_syscallname in a seccomp filter? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **use __NR_syscallname** (e.g., `__NR_chdir`). As per [the syscalls manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html):

> Roughly speaking, the code belonging to the system call with number __NR_xxx defined in /usr/include/asm/unistd.h can be found in the Linux kernel source in the routine sys_xxx().

The difference is that SYS_syscallname definitions are part of the libc, while __NR_syscallname definitions are from the Linux headers. I'm also not sure all __NR_syscallname have a SYS_syscallname alias.